# SAM lambda deployment - [ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'pydantic'

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'pydantic'

[image]

I use chalice and used this guide here to deploy container version of lambda: https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/1598#issuecomment-917511355

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN python3.9 -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t .

COPY deployment/ ./

CMD ["python3.9", "app.app"]
```

Checking deployment folder and requirements.txt I can see pydantic directory

[image]

And pydantic directory does exist within deployment directory. (root directory)

So why can't lambda find pydantic module?

opening docker built image in bash to run python and importing pydantic works fine.

It just seems that when the image is pushed to ECR and when lambda tries to run app.py it can't find the module.